# How to detect thread entry/spawn point in LLVM pass?

Tags: c++, multithreading, time, profiling, llvm

I am writing a profiler for which I want to know the total time since the thread was created as well as the total CPU time used by that thread for a certain calculation.

By ***total*** time I mean: the time including the time a thread spends being blocked for whatever reason, so total time elapsed since something like `thread my_thread(function)`.

`getrusage` gives me the CPU time for the calling thread which is good, however, I want to know the total time that passed since the thread was created as well. I couldn't find any C++ library for it at all.

I can take a time stamp when the thread was created/spawned by instrumenting the program and inserting a simple time stamp method like the `chrono` functions and then another time stamp when I do the calculation, their difference is the time I want. However, even after some search I couldn't figure out how to detect thread entry/spawn point using an LLVM pass.

Any suggestions on how to detect thread entry/spawn point in LLVM pass?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you need to search for `CallInst`s which call to `pthread_create`, then analyze their arguments and find out what callback function they are passed in.

To make sure you catch all thread creation calls, you'd need to research how threads are created on your platform. At the lowest level, thread creation requires syscall (well, in most cases).

For instance, FreeBSD does have a `pthread_create` function, but it is purely userland and delegates thread creation to `thr_new` syscall. Some programs (Rust language runtime, IIRC) may call into that syscall directly, bypassing `pthread_create`, but these are pretty rare. So, if you really want to make sure you catch every thread creation, you'd need to search `CallInst`s to these low level ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah I thought of that as well. But are there other ways to spawn a thread? Whill those ways be caught when I check the call inst of pthread_create? I dont think so.